# CoreWCF -The contract name could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, corewcf

I use this configuration for CoreWCF.
=>.NET Framework 4.7.2
=> CoreWCF Namespace

Here is my Web config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="bhv">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
          <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="bhv">
              <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>           
          </service>
      </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>


using System;
using CoreWCF;

namespace HelloService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IHelloService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
    }
}


using System;
using CoreWCF;

namespace HelloService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "HelloService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select HelloService.svc or HelloService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the service code here as well.
What might have gone wrong to make this service up?

Comment: Please show the class declaration including namespace of your C# implementation of the service.

Comment: FullyQualifiedServiceName is the name of your header, but FullyQualifiedIServiceName in your code, the lack of an `I`. This is the title wrong or is this.